# Installing libopnempi-dev on WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 failing

Tags: apt, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mpi

I'm  currently testing the waters on developing software with C++ and MPI and need some help.
I'm trying to install the openmpi headers on my machine on WSL with a Ubuntu 20.04. I can't seem to get the following command to succeed:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libopenmpi-dev
```

Here's the output. It's telling me that I'm missing some dependencies

[image]

I've tried installing whatever it tells me that's missing but I keep getting the missing dependencies error on those commands as well.

Can anyone help?

**Update:**

The issue was solved after I uninstalled my ubuntu form the WSL and reinstalled it from the Microsoft Store. I suspect this was being caused due to the fact that I updated to 20.04 from inside the WSL environment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.Does that error message disappear after running ```sudo apt update ; sudo apt-get install -y libopenmpi-dev``` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't but it turns out it solved itself when I uninstalled and made a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 on WSL. I think that it was being caused because I had updated to 20.04 from 18.00 from inside the WSL not by downloading it from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: So if you think that might help the future readers, please consider making an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved after I uninstalled my Ubuntu from the WSL and reinstalled it from the Microsoft Store. I suspect this was being caused due to the fact that I updated to 20.04 from inside the WSL environment.